# Preprocess (replace character) log body for syslog receiver

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I use opentelemetry-collector (contrib 0.82.0) and syslogreceiver. I'm getting error `parsed value was not rfc3164 or rfc5424 compliant` for some logs:

```
{
  "level": "error",
  "ts": 1693341000.02045,
  "caller": "helper/transformer.go:99",
  "msg": "Failed to process entry",
  "kind": "receiver",
  "name": "syslog",
  "data_type": "logs",
  "operator_id": "syslog_input_internal_parser",
  "operator_type": "syslog_parser",
  "error": "parsed value was not rfc3164 or rfc5424 compliant",
  "action": "send",
  "entry": {
    "observed_timestamp": "2023-08-29T20:30:00.020397777Z",
    "timestamp": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "body": "<7>Aug 29 16:30:00 dev app-logs: 2023-08-29 20:29:11,604 [app] ERROR error log\\n\tat backtrace",
    "severity": 0,
    "scope_name": ""
  },
  "stacktrace": "github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza/operator/helper.(*TransformerOperator).HandleEntryError\n\tgithub.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza@v0.82.0/operator/helper/transformer.go:99\ngithub.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza/operator/helper.(*ParserOperator).ParseWith\n\tgithub.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza@v0.82.0/operator/helper/parser.go:140\ngithub.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza/operator/helper.(*ParserOperator).ProcessWithCallback\n\tgithub.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza@v0.82.0/operator/helper/parser.go:112\ngithub.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza/operator/parser/syslog.(*Parser).Process\n\tgithub.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza@v0.82.0/operator/parser/syslog/syslog.go:153\ngithub.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza/operator/helper.(*WriterOperator).Write\n\tgithub.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza@v0.82.0/operator/helper/writer.go:53\ngithub.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza/operator/input/tcp.(*Input).handleMessage\n\tgithub.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza@v0.82.0/operator/input/tcp/tcp.go:321\ngithub.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza/operator/input/tcp.(*Input).goHandleMessages.func1\n\tgithub.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza@v0.82.0/operator/input/tcp/tcp.go:282"
}
```

Root cause is that log body message contains non printable characters (e.g. tabs in Java backtrace), which is violation of RFC3164. Problem is that I can't configure sender to follow RFC3164.

Can I configure some operator in syslog receiver, which will preprocess body message before real syslog RFC3164 collector parser to avoid this problem? I would say simple replace of `\t` -> `\\t` will be a solution.

Of course processor are designed for data modification, but I can't use any processor here, because problem is on the receiver level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can receive logs using the `tcp` or `udp` receiver, preprocess using `operators`, and then pass the data to the `syslog_parser` operator.

The following receiver configs are equivalent except that the second allows for preprocessing:

```yaml
receivers:
  syslog:
    tcp:
      listen_address: ...
    protocol: ...
  tcplog:
    listen_address: ...
    operators:
      # preprocess here
      - syslog_parser:
        protocol: ...
```

Tou can use the `add` operator to reformat and overwrite the log's body. Like many other operators, the `add` operator supports an [expression language](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/main/pkg/stanza/docs/types/expression.md) which contains a [replace](https://github.com/antonmedv/expr/blob/master/docs/Language-Definition.md#replacev-old-new) function.

```yaml
receivers:
  tcplog:
    listen_address: ...
    operators:
      - type: add
        field: body
        value: EXPR(replace(body, '\t', '\\t'))
      - type: syslog_parser
        protocol: rfc3164
```

Comment: It looks great. I will need to test is in real world. Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually, `add` operator is failing sometimes  - error: `evaluate value_expr: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Call on zero Value (1:1)\n | replace(body, '\\t', '\\\\t')\n | ^` - full error https://gist.github.com/jangaraj/0b2fc4a1755078e2f858a0e5f3722b14 Any idea why? I tried also `'EXPR(replace(body, "\t", "\\t"))'` with similar error result. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, it works like a charm with contrib `0.84.0` version. Thanks.